# How to get (from terminal) total number of threads per core?

Tags: cpu, process, cpu-load, top, proc

I want to know how can I get the total number of running threads per core (in the runqueue) in the terminal (to be used in a bash script)?

Comment: I know you can get a thread count with `dmidecode -t processor` but I don't know how to expand on it.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I think the "thread count" on dmidecode output is simply number of available runqueues (including physical cores and hyperthreads). For example, I disabled hyperthreading in my core i7 machine, and therefore I only have 4 threads (and 4 cores). But  that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for actual number of running threads on each runqueue.

Comment: I can't find anything particularly useful I am afraid. I have only ever used `ps -emo %cpu,pid,user,args` and then identified the PID# and then used `top -H -p PID#`  to troubleshoot.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I believe it's probably more complicated than what I was originally thinking. For example, these guys patched the scheduler's kernel to extract this information. https://github.com/jplozi/wastedcores/blob/master/tools/visualizations_4.1/sched_profiler/sched_profiler_linux_4.1.patch 
The final visualization is used here: http://www.ece.ubc.ca/~sasha/papers/eurosys16-final29.pdf
I want to come up with a similar visualization, but I really don't want to mess with the kernel and patches!

Comment: You could try **topline** you can get it from the Synaptic Package Manger.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to get the same information as figures 7 and 8 in [this article](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/atc18/atc18-bouron.pdf).
However, as you mentioned, the safest way is to patch the kernel, although it may affect the performance or is not a general solution working with every kernel version.

What I did was use [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) tools to record the traces of the scheduler's events.

For the event, you can also put a specific event using the list of events here:

```
$ perf list | grep sched
```

You can get the events in a file with the following command and then convert it to something readable as your desire.

```
$ perf record -e 'sched:*' -p <PID> sleep <seconds>
```

You can have the per CPU core information with a time stamp after you recorded the data with this command:

```
$ perf sched timehist -p <samePIDofRecorded> > time_history.txt
```

To get the pure raw text data:

```
$ perf script > perf.data.txt
```